# How to use count function in the below mentioned query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just want to know how to add count function in the below mentioned query in which I only have to display those records where count of p_id should equal to 1

```
select Distinct p_id,i.img_path as ImagesName, 
(
  select p.project_details from [Project] p where p.p_id=i.p_id
) as ProjectName
from [p_Image] i
```

Comment: What is that comment supposed to mean? Do you want to show us the pictures from your desktop?

Comment: I have three columns in the table one is p_id in which values are repeting twice and thrice so just want to count the p_id field and to display records where count=1

Comment: Don't post sample data in comments, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM(
    select 
        p_id, 
        i.img_path as ImagesName, 
        (
          select p.project_details from [Project] p where p.p_id=i.p_id
        ) as ProjectName,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id) CNT
    from [p_Image] i
)x WHERE CNT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p_id, i.img_path as ImagesName, p.project_details as ProjectName, count(*) as sum
from [p_Image] i
join [Project] p on (p.p_id=i.p_id)
group by p_id
having sum = 1;
```

Comment: That will not work. The use of `group by` like that is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalent to:

```
select p_id, i.img_path as ImagesName, p.project_details as ProjectName
from p_Image i left outer join
     project p
     on p.p_id=i.p_id;
```

Here are two ways to get "unique" p_id:

```
select p_id, min(i.img_path) as ImagesName, min(p.project_details) as ProjectName
from p_Image i left outer join
     project p
     on p.p_id = i.p_id
group by p_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

The logic:  when the count is 1, then the `min()` there is only one value for `img_path` and `project_details`.  The `min()` returns that value.

The following uses a subquery with a window function instead:

```
select p_id, ImagesName, ProjectName
from (select p_id, i.img_path as ImagesName, p.project_details as ProjectName,
             count(*) over (partition by p_id) as cnt
      from p_Image i left outer join
           project p
           on p.p_id=i.p_id
     ) pi
where cnt = 1;
```